# Switch from .bat to .py - duplicate logging

Tags: python-2.7, nosetests

I have a suite of tests I run with Nose and Python 2.7.

I used to run the suite with `runner.bat` file.

Using that, I would get nice logged output, like so:

```
2015-02-10 16:28:28,759 - DEBUG - Firefox version: 35.0
2015-02-10 16:28:28,788 - DEBUG - Running against Production on firefox
etc.
```

I want to port my .bat to .py for a number of reasons (mainly added functionality)

I have made a `runner.py` file.  It sits in the exact same dir as `runner.bat`  But now my logging is duplicated.

```
2015-02-10 17:04:57,315 - DEBUG - Firefox version: 35.0
2015-02-10 17:04:57,315 - DEBUG - Firefox version: 35.0
2015-02-10 17:04:57,355 - DEBUG - Running against Production on firefox
2015-02-10 17:04:57,355 - DEBUG - Running against Production on firefox
```

I tried adding `logger.propogate=False` to my logging object, but no luck. Anyone have ideas as to why I suddenly get duplicates when running with a .py?

**LogManager.py**

```
def configure_logging():

    # Log to file    
    fileHandler = FileHandler(logging_path)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.propagate = False

configure_logging()
```

**Runner.bat**

```
@echo off
IF EXIST C:\TestOutput\version.txt del C:\TestOutput\version.txt

python C:\TestSuite\Utils\cleanup_logging_output_dir.py

nosetests -a level=gold
```

**Runner.py**

```
import os
import sys
import socket
import nose
import tempfile
import shutil


def prepare_tests():

    ... do lots of stuff ...

    os.system("python {} {}".format(clean_log_script, config_dir)

    nose_argv = [__file__, '-a', 'level=gold', '--with-id']

    ... augment nose_argv if needed based on other variables...

    return nose_argv

######################
### Run nosetests  ###
######################
test_argv = prepare_tests()
result = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # don't run tests on current file
    test_argv.extend(['--ignore-files', os.path.basename(__file__)])

    result = nose.run(argv=test_argv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is a bug in Nose.  The following produces duplicate logging:

```
 logger = logging.getLogger("general_logger")
```

However the following does not:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [logging_tree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree) right before you use your `logger.debug()`, something like this:

```
from logging_tree import printout; printout()
```

It will give you a nice printout of the logging hierarchy, as well as an indication if logger has `Propagate OFF` set or not. Make sure you understand what it returns to you and you have set `propagate = False` to the right loggers. Also make sure to run nose with `-s` so that you can see the printout.

Comment: Neat tool, logging_tree.  I see that `Propogate OFF` is set for the correct logger, but there are duplicate handler files, hence the duplication.  I'm running `printout()` immediately after I `configure_logging()`.  Not sure why duplicates would be there so immediately.